# Deconstructing a project tango ADF file. Does anyone know anything about the format of the internals for this file?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to deconstruct the ADF file from project tango to try to grab the metadata as well as understand what is in the thing.  Does anyone have any information on this?  Does anyone have any example ADFs I could poke through as I don't have a tango device?

Thanks!

Comment: This question may be off topic for SO since it asks for an off site resource

Comment: Deconstructing ADF is not something we suggest to do. Why do you need to deconstruct it in the first place?